# How to render favicon in head of v4.master

Tags: html, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

In my v4.master on SharePoint Server 2010 I have the following markup

```
<head runat="server">
   ...
   <SharePoint:SPShortcutIcon runat="server" IconUrl="/Path/to/icon.ico" />
</head>
```

Alternativley I tried

```
<link rel="Shortcut Icon" href="/Path/to/icon.ico />
```

After the page has been rendered, this link tag is located in the `body` and ignored by Chrome (IE11, latest FireFox do render the favicon in the body section).
Is there a way to let SharePoint render this in the `<head>` section?

Answer (score 0):

Use "PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" in your page layout.
And add the code you would like to push into Head section of your master mage

Comment: You should really add some explanation as to why this should work - you can also add code as well as the comments in the code itself 
- in its current form, it does not provide any explanation which can help the rest of the community to understand what you did to solve/answer the question. This is especially important for an older question and the questions that already have answers.